# Use case of the code

Tags: apex, code, business-logic

On exploring collections, I came across the following code:

> String myName = [select Id, managerName, address__c from User where Id =: userInfo.getUserId()].managerName;

I see that **myName** will have the name of a **managerName**. Is myName useless because I can't possibly have **Id** and **address__c** in it?

What can be the possible use case for this code? I can't think of any, probably blind to see the big picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just gets you the value of the running user's `ManagerName`. You might have business logic dependent on that data point. Not sure what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of code is often written when you only care about one field in the query result. While rare, some business logic does require just one specific value from one specific record. It does have a valid use case, it's just incredibly uncommon.

For example, this code is getting the manager name from the current user; this is the only value needed from the user in that specific block of code. The extra fields queried are superfluous, because their values are immediately discarded.

If you wanted all the fields, you'd save the entire user record:

```
User currentUser = [select managername, address__c from user where Id = :UserInfo.getId()];
```

Using the retrieve-one-field-from-one-record syntax is most likely to appear in code that is not used in bulk, like some Visualforce pages, but I've also seen (and used) this type of code in a trigger, usually because one value needs to be applied to all records in the current context.

Some utility classes might also benefit from this pattern. For example, maybe the current manger's name is used in many places, so this might consolidate code by running the query just once per transaction.

Comment: Just adding the point that this type of query should only be used when you know for sure that the record exists such when using global variables. using this type of query when the possibility exists can lead to DNO errors and generally should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation @sfdcfox.  Eric I Tried googling a DNO error, couldn't find any!